# Magical Record saving error

Tags: magicalrecord

Now I'm trying to develop iCloud app with Magical Record.

When saving, EXC_BAD_ACCESS error occurred in MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer:@"com.sample.SampleApp" localStoreNamed:@"SampleApp.sqlite"];
    NSManagedObjectContext *magicalContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];

    Cat* magicalCat1 = [Cat MR_createEntity];
    magicalCat1.name = @"mike";

    [magicalContext MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait];
}
```

The actual part error occurred is the following

```
    @try
    {
        saveResult = [self save:&error];  <-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurred here
    }
    @catch(NSException *exception)
    {
        MRLogError(@"Unable to perform save: %@", (id)[exception userInfo] ?: (id)[exception reason]);
    }
```

Please give me any advice to fix this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is "magicalContext" there? How is it created?

Comment: @casademora Thanks for your advice. I made a mistake when I copied from my source code. I added `NSManagedObjectContext *magicalContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];`

Comment: I'm going to suggest using MagicalRecord 3.0. Check it out on the releases/3.0 branch. This changes the way iCloud support is used, and should work properly for iOS7 and newer.

Comment: @casademora thanks for your reply. I'm sure I use the latest library. I downloaded July 1st from GitHub. Do you know any complete sample of Magical Records using iCloud?

Comment: I assure you, you are NOT on the latest code if this is the sample of your usage.

Comment: @casademora thanks for your advice. I'll try to download the library again.